# How to remove date/time stamp from Facebook comments plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

at the bottom of this page (https://go.microgreensfarmer.com/video1) you will see I added the Facebook comments plugin.  Well I would love to get rid of the date/time that is listed along with each comment. Is this possible?

Here is the Javascript SDK I have in the body:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'your-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.9'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And here is the HTML I have on the page:

```html
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://microgreensfarmer.com" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5" order_by="reverse_time"></div>
```

Any way to edit these so date/time is not displayed alongside comment?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for you, this is not possible using Facebook's comments plugin. This is probably because Facebook wants to show its own identity.  For full details of the plugin and the options you have, you can take a look here (If you haven't already)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

Sorry!

Comment: Thanks Thomas!  That stinks, are you aware of any commenting plugins that would allow no date/time to be displayed?  I couldn't figure out how to do it with discus either...

Comment: You can take a look at talkatv, https://github.com/talkatv/talkatv. it's open source, so it's easy to make adjustments